# How do I prevent a SWIFT 4.2 run-time error when a storyboard cannot be found or hasn't been created yet?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I am doing a 30-day course to learn SWIFT 4.2 and the starter project has a table view to showcase 30 apps, one per day. So, there are day-specific storyboards.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var dataModel = NavModel.getDays()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: nil, action: nil)

    }

    // MARK: uitableview delegate and datasource
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print ("This is dataModel.count: ", dataModel.count)
        return dataModel.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! ContentTableViewCell
        cell.data = dataModel[indexPath.row]
        print(cell.data!)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let dayCount = dataModel[indexPath.row].dayCount
        print("This is dayCount: ", dayCount)
        let initViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Day\(dayCount)", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(initViewController!, animated: true)

    }
}
```

How do I update this code snippet:

```
let initViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Day\(dayCount)", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
```

to prevent the app from crashing if the app cannot find a specific storyboard that doesn't exist yet?

Here is the code for NavModel.swift:

```
import UIKit 

class NavModel { 

    var dayCount: Int 
    var title: String 
    var color: UIColor 

    init(count: Int, title: String, color: UIColor) { 
        self.dayCount = count 
        self.title = title 
        self.color = color 
    } 

    class func getDays() -> [NavModel] { 
        var model = [NavModel]() 
        for i in 1...30 { 
            let nav = NavModel(count: i, title: "Day (i)", color: UIColor.randomFlatColor()) 
            model.append(nav) 
        } 
        return model 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prevent that code from crashing. Being unable to find the referenced storyboard is a fatal error that cannot be caught.

Referring to a storyboard that isn't your bundle is something you want to know about during testing.

The appropriate solution is to change the data model so that it only contains data for which you have storyboards. ie, if today is day 10, then `NavModel.getDays()` should only return 10 data items.

*I* would re-write the `NavModel` as:

```
import UIKit

struct NavModel {

    let dayNumber: Int
    var title: String {
        get {
            return "Day \(dayNumber)"
        }
    }
    let color: UIColor


    static func getDays(count: Int) -> [NavModel] {
        var model = [NavModel]()
        for i in 1...count {
            model.append(NavModel(dayNumber: i, color: UIColor.randomFlatColor()))
        }
        return model
    }
}
```

And then create the model as, say, `NavModel.getDays(count:10)`

Comment: I appreciate the thoughtful response. I replaced the NaveModel.swift as suggested. How can I create the model in the ViewController.swift file without hardcoding it as 10 days?

Comment: You can't.  You need to hard code.  The only way you can add storyboards is by rebuilding your app, so when you do that you change the hard-coded value.

Comment: Okay, I will close as the answer.